# 1 Billion records join(Filters) in Spark with Parquet file format vs HadoopText Input format

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parquet

When reading a 1 Billion records of a table in Spark from Hive and this table have date and country columns as partitions. It is running for very long time since we are doing many transformations on it. If I change the Hive table file format to Parquet then will it be there any performance? Any suggestions on improvement of performance .

Comment: it depends on whether loading and filtering the data is the bottle neck, or if your other operations are. It will speed up the reading of data a lot, and should push down filters more efficiently, but it won't make the follow-up steps any more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Orc to Parquet maybe will not improve the performance.

But it depends of the type of data you have. If you are working with nested objects you need to use Parquet, Orc is not good for that.

But to create some improvement, I suggest you to do some steps that can help with your data in Hive.

### Check the number of files in Hive.

One common thing that can create big problems in Hive Query is the number of files in each partition, and the size of these files are. If you are using Spark to store the data, I suggest you to check the size of the files and if they are stored with the size of your Hadoop block. If not, try to use the command `CONCATENATE` to solve that problem. As you can see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate).

### Predicate PushDown

This is what Hive, and Orc files can give you with the best performance in query the data. I suggest you to run one `ANALYSE` command to force the creation of the Statistics of your table, this will improve the performance and if the data is not efficient this will help. Check [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE) and with this will update the Hive Metastore and will give you some relevant data information.

### Ordered Data

If it is possible, try to store your data ordered by some column, and filter and do other stuffs in that column. Your join can be improved with this.